# Efficiently check role claim

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, claims

I'm developing an Asp.NET MVC5 web application (.NET 4.6) and I need to show some extra lines of HTML to a group of users with a specific claim. I've seen some verbose solutions but I prefer to keep it short, so I came up with this

```
@{
    if (System.Security.Claims.ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims.ToList().FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "role" && c.Value == "AwesomeUserRole") != null) {
        <!-- my HTML goes here -->
    }
 }
```

Is it a good way to check for an authenticated user claim or is there a best practice to follow? Any cleaner / more efficient solution is welcome as well.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Because all `Identity` objects in ASP.NET are now a `ClaimsIdentity`, you could always cast the current `IPrincipal` to a `ClaimsIdentity`:

```
((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).HasClaim("role", "AwesomeUserRole")
```

But it is actually easiest to just use `User.IsInRole("AwesomeUserRole")`

As long as you haven't changed the default configuration, claims with the type of `role` are automatically fed into the roles collection for the thread principal.

If you need to check for additional claim types besides roles, I usually create a set of extension methods for `IPrincipal` that wrap the claim checks:

```
public static bool CanDoX(this IPrincipal principal)
{
    return ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).HasClaim(claimType, claimValue);
}
```

The benefit of the extension method is that you can check for any kind of claim and return any values they may contain, not just whether or not the claim exists.

Comment: ((System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity).HasClaim("role", "miAdmin") and User.IsInRole("miAdmin") don't return the same value for me.  The first is correct for me.  Not sure why User.IsInRole("miAdmin") isn't working.

Comment: Check that the Identity is using "role" as its role claim type, the default is a uri

Comment: `claims with the type of role are automatically fed into the roles collection for the thread principal` This line really helped. Thanks

Answer (score 16):

Bear in mind that a Principal can have more than one identity associated with it, e.g. you have authenticated with Windows Authentication, but then added a custom identity with claims from your database.

So any claim check potentially needs to look at all identities, here's a couple of extension methods that will help

```
public static bool ClaimExists(this IPrincipal principal, string claimType)
{
    var ci = principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
    if (ci == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var claim = ci.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == claimType);

    return claim != null;
}

public static bool HasClaim(this IPrincipal principal, string claimType,
                            string claimValue, string issuer = null)
{
    var ci = principal as ClaimsPrincipal;
    if (ci == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var claim = ci.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type == claimType
                                         && x.Value == claimValue
                                         && (issuer == null || x.Issuer == issuer));

    return claim != null;
}
```